# Stackview inside Other stackview width issue

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have an Stackview created in IB and it has Vertical orientation. This stackview has equal width to parent view.

Now I am created a Stackview programmatically for example

```
let stackViewHorizontal   = UIStackView()
    stackViewHorizontal.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
    stackViewHorizontal.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.fillEqually
    stackViewHorizontal.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.leading
    stackViewHorizontal.spacing = 8
    stackViewHorizontal.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackViewHorizontal.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainStackView.leadingAnchor,constant:0)
    stackViewHorizontal.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainStackView.trailingAnchor,constant:0)
```

Here mainStackView is a stackview which is created Via IB.and stackviewHorizontal is a stackview that is created programatically. 
I am putting to UILabels inside stackViewHorizontal.  I expected this will expand to full length and each UiLabel will take 50% of the screen in width since stackview has horizontal axis and distribution is fillEqually.

But I am having a UiLabels next to eachother horizontally. but not taking full width of screen

What I am doing wrong please notify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activate constraints, also give it a height:

```swift
    stackViewHorizontal.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainStackView.leadingAnchor,constant:0).isActive = true
    stackViewHorizontal.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainStackView.trailingAnchor,constant:0).isActive = true
```

**OR**

```swift
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
       stackViewHorizontal.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainStackView.leadingAnchor,constant:0), 
       stackViewHorizontal.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainStackView.trailingAnchor,constant:0) 
    ])
```

//

```swift
    let stackViewHorizontal   = UIStackView()
    stackViewHorizontal.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
    stackViewHorizontal.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.fillEqually
    stackViewHorizontal.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.leading
    stackViewHorizontal.spacing = 8
    self.view.addSubview(stackViewHorizontal) //// add it here 
    stackViewHorizontal.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackViewHorizontal.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainStackView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    stackViewHorizontal.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainStackView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Comment: after activiating it is crashed

Comment: because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: add it to the shared parent view between them which is self.view before adding constraints

Comment: I didnt understand